# Javascript - how to get input type file's properties - mainly Title and Type of file?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fonts

For a text editor, I need to get user uploaded font file's actual name, which is available in file's title property. So, how can I get file's title and type with javascript?

As displayed in this link- https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhWJ3.png

Comment: I found this article -http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. Here files last modified date has retrieved. So, is there a way to get Title of file this way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "title" property.

If you mean that a user is uploading a font, and the name of the file they are uploading actually contains the font they're uploading, and by "type" you mean the MIME type, then yes, those are pretty much the only things you *can* know about a file, before it's sent to the server (without using the FileReader API, which isn't fully supported everywhere, yet...  ...when XP and Vista and BlackBerry and iPad 1, et cetera, die, then you can expect/demand people to have it -- depending on your clients, you might be able to jump in right now, or not for another 5 years).

```
<input type="file" id="myFileInput">
```

JS:

```
var input = document.querySelector("#myFileInput"),
    info  = input.files[0];

info.name; // my-font-name.woff
info.type; // application/font-woff
```

Of course, anybody can modify either of those things, really easily, so there'd better be some security in the back-end.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the font files are usually not renamed to what is there actual name. Like- Linds.ttf font's actual name is Lindsey. So,to use a user uploaded font as an elements font-family, the actual name of the font is needed which is somehow a font file's title. So, I was wondering if there is a way to get the title like here- info.title or something. Reading the file API from http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ I think I am unlucky to get the title of file from user side. By title I meant this- http://i.imgur.com/AbVsblX.png

Comment: No.  You need to run the file reader API, then know how to parse the file and file headers for that exact file type, and then you can read the title metadata